# Cancel validation on rich:tabPanel switch

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

i try to create a unified login/register-page. We use a TabPanel for this. One tab to register, the other to login. The user should select what to do and then fill the inputs.

The problem ist: the registration has many required inputs. Therefore, if you want to switch from registration-tab to login-tab the validator strikes and prints error messages about the non-filled inputfiels. Is there a way to disable the validation on tab-switching or to deligate vefification to a bean-function. in this function i could validate by myself according to the selected tab.

Any ideas?

```
<h:form>
    //some inputs
    <rich:tabPanel id="panelRegisterLogin" switchType="server" activeItem="#{bean.registerLoginStatus}" itemChangeListener="#{bean.updateRegisterLoginStatus}">
        <rich:tab header="logIn" id="logIn" name="logIn">
            //inputs to log in an existing user
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="Register" id="registerNow" name="registerNow">
            //inputs to register a new user connected to managed bean
                    //some of them are required="true"
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>

    //submit-button
</h:form>
```

Comment: Try switchType client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `immediate="true"` to the whole `rich:tabPanel`, or to individual `rich:tab` elements.

> immediate
>
> Flag indicating that this component's value must be converted and
>   validated immediately (that is, during Apply Request Values phase),
>   rather than waiting until Process Validations phase.

Comment: I tried this before, but only at the `rich:tabPanel`, not at the `rich:tab`s. If i put it on the tabs, it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Tobias Hm, it works for me also when I put it at tabPanel only. What is the RichFaces version you are using?